# Scripts Causing Flash Intro Animation To Freeze

Tags: javascript, flash

When my Flash website loads, it freezes halfway through the initial animation for 2-3 seconds and then continues. This obviously doesn't look great and I can't figure out what is causing it. Am thinking it is one of the scripts in index.html and have tried all sorts of ways to correct it - what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>company name</title>
    .
    .
    .
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flashobject.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <hgroup>
    <h1>company</h1>
    <h2>company</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>

<div id="container">    
    <div id="head">
        <div class="aligncenter"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/EN_US-H-GET-FLASH">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_adobe_flash_player.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>                      
</div>
    <div class="g-plus" data-href="https://plus.google.com/100925740920754223119?rel=publisher" data-width="170" data-height="69" data-theme="light">   

</body>

<!-- Flash -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fo = new FlashObject("main_v10.swf", "head", "100%", "100%", "8", "");
  fo.addParam("quality", "high");
  fo.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
  fo.write("head");
</script>

<!-- Hello Bar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.hellobar.com/hellobar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new HelloBar(39040,52484);
</script>

<!-- GPlus -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en'};
(function() 
{var po = document.createElement("script");
po.type = "text/javascript"; po.async = true;po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();</script>

<!-- Google -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 10]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function init() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);
 })();
  window.onload = init;
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: have you tried embedding the SWF into a blank html page to see if the error still occurs, if it does then its the SWF causing the problem

Comment: Yes have tried this and it runs fine. Thx

Comment: im hoping your online, is it possible to send me the animation, if not can you tell me how big the file size is and if the animation consist of buttons or interactivity, giving me this info will allow me to test it better. i have uploaded your script to a test server you can see here www.gamezslave.net/test/blank.html

Comment: If you examine the 'timeline' tab in e.g. Chrome's developer tools, you should be able to see what's happening during the pause.

Comment: Thanks @jimw - hadn't thought of using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the Hello Bar part to see if it changes something.
If it does, either the script in the file linked is ridiculously slow, or the server on which the script is is ridiculously slow. And since script loading and executing is blocking, it might be the source of the freeze.

In this case, you could try with defer or async attributes on the script tag but then you would need to rewrite

```
new HelloBar(39040,52484);
```

as

```
function HelloBar( ) { window.setTimeout( function ( a, b ) { new HelloBar( a, b ); }, 100 ); }
new HelloBar(39040,52484);
```

This way, when you script loads, HelloBar gets overwritten, the "loop" stops and your script is invoked with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good question.  It is too specific to your servers, computer, OS, browser, and internet connection to be a question with a general answer.  But here are my results:

I am using Firefox (latest) on Windows.

G+ and the Adobe icon are loading slowly for me on the test I ran.  I think you can bring the Adobe icon can be put on your local server.  Beyond that, you are making some potentially slow calls to HelloBar and G+, so consider adding those links in after some sort of delay (use jQuery or similar).

Also, I have had issues with slow loading with Google analytics in the past.  This also seems to duplicate some of the functionality of HelloBar, so you may want to look more closely whether you need both tracking systems.

For more precision on finding the problem, you can use what @jimw suggested or else use the Firefox plugin Firebug (use the "Net" tabs's "All" button to get a picture of the load times).

Comment: Its a website, so I want to know if there is an error in the code / markup on the index.html page that is causing the issue. The question is perfectly reasonable! I will look at the Hello Bar code and remove it to see if there is any difference. Thx

Comment: I didn't say the q. wasn't reasonable, it's just not a good one.  It can't be answered unless someone can replicate your environment, and that is nearly impossible.  But, as far as it goes, you are not describing an "error", but, rather, a "feature".  That is, any calls to remote websites may be slow; any heavy Javascript (e.g., jQuery) loads, too.  The best advice in all this is using Firebug plugin for Firefox, or Google Chrome.  Post the results from those debuggeres if they are not clear to you, and someone can help you out.